# Remove Admin Toolbar "Manage" item if User has No Access

Tags: 8, navigation, toolbar

I have created Tours for my users and allowed them to see the Admin Toolbar as a result. However, I have the following unpleasant toolbar:

[image]

I would like the "Manage" item to be gone altogether when there's only the Logout & Home link. How could I achieve such behavior?

Note: I've tried disabling the Tools item in the Administrative menu UI and that kinda works, but the Manage item is still displayed.

Comment: I'm new to drupal as well, but not new to programming. I have the same question, there is nothing easy about drupal. (Pulling my hair out)

Comment: @Chad, see d70rr3s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLTTP;

Is a core bug since 6.4 version (https://www.drupal.org/node/296693) you can use the latest version of admin_toolbar (https://drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) which haves a submodule specific for that issue. Unfortunately this only works for 'admin_menu' menu but not the toolbar menu (the black bar on top). To hide specific toolbar elements or toolbar element tray links (toolbar element links) you can implement `hook_toolbar_alter(&$items)` hook (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!toolbar!toolbar.api.php/8.5.x).

Hope it helps someone.